# Transposing the list based on property names in C#

Tags: c#, linq

I have a class with the following properties

```
    public class Curve
    {
        public string CurveName { get; set; }

        public string RefSource { get; set; }
        public int price1 { get; set; }
        public int price2 { get; set; }
        public int price3 { get; set; }

        public static List<Curve> GetCurveList()
        {
            List<Curve> data = new List<Curve>()
            {
                new Curve() { CurveName="Lamar", price1 = 1, price2 = 101,price3=104,RefSource="Tome" },
                new Curve() { CurveName="Lamar", price1 = 2, price2 = 201,price3=204,RefSource="Richard" }
    }
```

I need it to get transformed in another list as following properties

```
curveName=lamar,refSource=richard ,hour=(name of the property of price1, price2,price3)taking integer of the last part of the enclosed property,value associated with the price property

curveName=lamar,refSource=Tom,hour=(name of the property of price1, price2,price3)taking integer of the last part of the enclosed property,value associated with the price property
```

basically the two items of the source list should result into a new list of 6 rows based on the refsource and each property captioned as price and it need to look like below

```
Name    RefSource   Hour    Value
lamar   tom        1           1
lamar   tom        2         101
lamar   tom        3         104
lamar   richard    1          2
lamar   richard    2         201
lamar   richard    3         204
```

The hour column is suffix of property name `Price1`, `price2`, `price3` in the source list.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var query =
    from curve in Curve.GetCurveList()
    from result in new []
    {
        new { curve.CurveName, curve.RefSource, Hour = 1, Value = curve.price1 },
        new { curve.CurveName, curve.RefSource, Hour = 2, Value = curve.price2 },
        new { curve.CurveName, curve.RefSource, Hour = 3, Value = curve.price3 },
    }
    select result;
```

That gives me:

[image: results]

Comment: Thanks for your reply and correctly editing my question, i am new to stack exchange,, however in your reply you have hardcoded the hour value but i need the hour value as the suffix of the property of Pricei so that in hour for a property Price7 -7 should be hour and similarly for property 'Value'=price7 value should be used
Thanks in advance

Comment: @NISHET - Your object must have a fixed number of these properties, right? So it doesn't make sense to me that you have to somehow dynamically generate these values. Can you please explain in more detail what you're doing?